# Mouseover with an image and a caption in Aframe

Tags: aframe

I would like to display an image along with a caption when the mouse move over an image in Aframe.

Answer (score 0):

To use Your mouse as a cursor, use `<a-scene cursor="rayOrigin:mouse">`

Then make a component listenening for the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events, displaying Your entities, and hiding them respectively.

**HTML**

```
<a-entity id="parent" listener>
     <a-entity id="images_and_captions"></a-entity>
</a-entity>
```

**JS**

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('listener', {
  init: function() {
    this.el.addEventListener('mouseenter', (e) => {
      this.el.children[0].setAttribute('visible', 'true');
    })
    this.el.addEventListener('mouseleave', (e) => {
      this.el.children[0].setAttribute('visible', 'false');
    })
  }
})
```

working fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/ou7r9hou/2/

Answer (score 0):

you'll want to add the `mouseenter` `eventlistener` to the object.

HTML

```
<img alt="img" id="img" src="myimg"/>
```

.

Javascript

```
window.onload = function(){
  var img = document.getElementById("img");
  img.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(){
      //your code to show image and text here
  });
}
```

You can ofcourse swap out the HTML for basicly anything in aframe and it would work as long as you keep the id.